# Splitting a csv into multiple csv of maximum 2000 rows while respecting grouping condition using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

This is my very first question...

I'm trying to split a big csv of **maximum** 2000 rows. If it was just splitting it would be too easy. In this case, I can't just split by dividing the csv. Indeed, some rows need to be grouped together. Every file can't be bigger (it can be smaller) than 2000 but mostly, **rows that needs to be together should be in the same file**. Rows that needs to be together share the same combination for two columns --> That's how I know they need to be together.

Example with 10 records and split csv's of maximum 5 rows :

| Country | Category | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | A | 1 |
| Spain | A | 2 |
| Spain | A | 3 |
| Spain | B | 4 |
| Spain | B | 5 |
| Spain | B | 6 |
| Spain | B | 7 |
| Italy | B | 8 |
| Germany | A | 9 |
| Germany | A | 10 |

**Here all the rows having the same combination of Country and Category need to be together**. If the maximum size of the split file is 5, we get the following:

| Country | Category | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | A | 1 |
| Spain | A | 2 |
| Spain | A | 3 |

| Country | Category | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | B | 4 |
| Spain | B | 5 |
| Spain | B | 6 |
| Spain | B | 7 |
| Italy | B | 8 |

| Country | Category | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | A | 9 |
| Germany | A | 10 |

Any idea how I could solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest to convert the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame (or use pd.read_csv) and do all the sorting and 'splitting' (creating new subset Data Frames  using Pandas commands.

Comment: issue is that I could have an initial file with thousands of rows and literally hundreds of combination of Country/Category. And I can't have hundreds of csv files as results. That's just not an option. It needs to be grouped in csv files of +/- 2000 rows...

Comment: Yes, so why not use Pandas to sort the bif CSV file on 'Country' and convert the subset selection to a new Pandas or CSV file, and do the same for 'Category' and 'Product'.

Comment: Why wouldn't the two Germanys be grouped with the three Spains? Same Category and that would be five lines.

Comment: Does it need to be OPTIMIZED at max lines per file or just grouped but Category then Country?

Comment: @dawg you're correct, Germany could be grouped with the three Spains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find group sizes, then calculate which group should be the last in each file (the point at which it overflows the given maximum number of rows), then convert it to file numbers and group by file numbers to save individual CSVs.

In code this would look like the following (please see comments for explanation):

```
# set max records per file
N = 5

# find counts per group
z = df.groupby(['Country', 'Category'], sort=False).size().reset_index()

# find the last group in each file and set `x` = 1
i = 0
for j in range(len(z)):
    if z.loc[i:j, 0].sum() > N:
        z.loc[j, 'x'] = 1
        i = j

# calculate the file number `f` as the cumsum of `x`
z['f'] = z['x'].fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int) + 1

# merge df and z to get file number for each record
# then groupby and save to separate CSV files
for f, df_g in df.merge(z[['Country', 'Category', 'f']]).groupby('f'):
    df_g.drop(columns='f').to_csv(f'{f:03}.csv', index=False)
```

This would save your sample DataFrame into 3 files:

1. 001.csv

```
  Country Category  Product
0   Spain        A        1
1   Spain        A        2
2   Spain        A        3
```

2. 002.csv

```
  Country Category  Product
0   Spain        B        4
1   Spain        B        5
2   Spain        B        6
3   Spain        B        7
4   Italy        B        8
```

3. 003.csv

```
   Country Category  Product
0  Germany        A        9
1  Germany        A       10
```

Comment: This seems to be working.. thanks a lot for that! I will test further and let you know. One more question, if I may. Since the max bucket size is 5, is there a way to fill all of them when possible? or is it that when the script initiate a new file, it's not possible to go back and fill a previous one? For example, after the 3 first rows, the script needs to move to the second bucket because we have 4 Spains/B but then it could add the Italy/B to the first file and not the second one? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I also made the hypothesis with my example that when we move to a new file, we don't go back and fill the space left of previous buckets with rows that now fit but I wonder if it's actually possible

Comment: @HugoWolf It's possible, but becomes a pretty difficult optimisation problem. Say you have 2-1-4-3. Our current approach would group it as (2-1)-(4)-(3), but an optimal is of course (2-3)-(4-1), which is not achievable by simply going back and checking if we can fill the remaining space (we would need to reshuffle the whole thing)

Comment: @HugoWolf If you're interested, these things can be optimized with [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), and there are tools like CPLEX and Gurobi for solving this kind of problems (among many others, of course, such as logistics, scheduling etc.), I'm just not sure it will be worth your while for this task

Comment: Thanks @perl. I will give it a look!

Comment: Also note that I needed to create the column x before looping through the rows. Just add z['x'] = np.nan and it's fine. (using Python 3.8.2)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
    Country   Category  Product
0   Spain     a         1
1   Belgium   b         2
2   Spain     a         2
3   Cuba      c         3
4   Belgium   c         4
5   Cuba      a         5

new_df = df[df['Country']=='Spain']

    Country Category    Product
0   Spain   a           1
2   Spain   a           2
```

Then convert the subset to a new CSV subset file. (do the same for 'category' and 'product')

```
new_df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: I believe he indicated that the selections need to factor in Category as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an **optimal** solution but it is an easy and tractable solution that is likely good enough.

```
import csv 
from itertools import groupby 

with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    header=next(reader)
    data=[row for row in reader]
    
def key_func(li):
    return (li[1],li[0],li[2])

data_dic={}
# If you only want a single country in a file, change the following line to
# for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=key_func), key=lambda li: (li[0], li[1])):
for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=key_func), key=lambda li: li[1]):
    data_dic[k]=list(v)

chnk=5  # change this for the max lines per file
cnt=1
for k,v in data_dic.items():
    for chunk in (v[i:i+chnk] for i in range(0, len(v), chnk)):
        print(f'\n=== file {cnt}:')
        cnt+=1
        print('\n'.join([','.join(e) for e in [header]+chunk]))
```

With your example, prints:

```
=== file 1:
Country,Category,Product
Germany,A,10
Germany,A,9
Spain,A,1
Spain,A,2
Spain,A,3

=== file 2:
Country,Category,Product
Italy,B,8
Spain,B,4
Spain,B,5
Spain,B,6
Spain,B,7
```

With this input:

```
Country,Category,Product
Spain,A,1
Spain,A,2
Spain,A,3
Spain,A,4
Spain,B,4
Spain,B,5
Spain,B,6
Spain,B,7
Spain,B,8
Italy,B,8
Germany,A,9
Germany,A,10
Germany,A,11
Cuba,C,22
```

Prints:

```
=== file 1:
Country,Category,Product
Germany,A,10
Germany,A,11
Germany,A,9
Spain,A,1
Spain,A,2

=== file 2:
Country,Category,Product
Spain,A,3
Spain,A,4

=== file 3:
Country,Category,Product
Italy,B,8
Spain,B,4
Spain,B,5
Spain,B,6
Spain,B,7

=== file 4:
Country,Category,Product
Spain,B,8

=== file 5:
Country,Category,Product
Cuba,C,22
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!! I'll test and let you know. Just out of curiosity, why is it not optimal?

Comment: It is close since it is sorting on Category then Country and then grouping by that then shortening to max of `chnk=` lines. An optimal solution would find a file that has X lines available and a chunk that would fit in that X that is otherwise out of sort order. More work...

Comment: I see. Well the issue with this solution is that the combination Spain/A is split across two files (1 and 2) and this is what we need to avoid. If they have the same Country/Category then they should be in the same file

Comment: That is avoided entirely with `for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=key_func), key=lambda li: (li[0], li[1])):`